# Jenkins in Docker container refuses to to install anything

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ansible, jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance running in a docker container running on an AWS EC2 instance with security group allowing traffic on ports 22, 80, and 8080. I use Ansible to install both: docker and Jenkins. The Jenkins role looks like this:

```
- name: Start Jenkins Container
  docker_container:
    name: Jenkins
    image: jenkins:latest
    state: started
    ports: 8080:8080

- name: Get Jenkins default password
  command: docker exec -it Jenkins bash -c 'cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword'
  register: hello

- debug: msg="{{ hello.stdout }}"
```

I can access the Setup Wizzard, I pass the password from the /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword file and when it comes to plugins installations they all fail to install. I can skip the installation and go to the Dashboard but there I see the message about three problems:

https://justpaste.it/1zv4r

Can you help me to understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will have use a newer version of Jenkins. Instead of specifying latest as your image tag, it would be better practice to specify a specific version. From the looks of your log, it looks like the highest number version it is requesting is v2.150. You are currently installing v2.60.3.

I would recommend specifying the latest version found here: https://jenkins.io/changelog/